# irregularities in partition function modulo n

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

It is an open problem whether the partition function is even half the time. Inspired by this, I wrote some Sage/Python code to check how many times $p(n)$ hits each residue class:

```
def partitionmod(n, k):
    bins = [0,] * k
    for i in range(n):
        bins[mod(Partitions(i+1).cardinality(), k)] += 1
    binstotal = 0
    for x in bins:
        binstotal += x
    for x in bins:
        print(N(x/binstotal, 30))
```

For $n = 50000$ and $k = 5$, I found something odd: the residue class of $0$ is hit with likelihood $.364$, which is double the odds of hitting any other residue class mod 5. Something similar happens with
$$k = 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 25, 28, 30,\dots$$
Is there something special about multiples of 5, 7, and 11 that I'm missing?

Comment: 5, 7, 11 is indeed special and was observed by Ramanujan. Proving the distribution results seem out of reach at the moment however. See MO post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293551/equidistribution-of-the-partition-function (as mentioned there, one expects $p(n) \equiv 0 \mod 5$ to happen 1/3 of the time), and particular Ono's paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0008140